# Boost Serialization: Transition from versioned class to object_serializable

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

TLDR: I would like to transition a class serialisation from implementation level `object_class_info` to `object_serializable`, keeping compatibility with old data files while always writing files in the new format.

Rationale: When I started using the Boost Serialization library, I didn’t realise that it already came with a header ([complex.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/boost/serialization/complex.hpp)) to serialise `std::complex<double>`. Instead, I wrote my own, free-standing serialisation function:

```
namespace boost { namespace serialization {
  template<class Archive, typename T>
  void serialize(Archive& ar, std::complex<T>& comp, const unsigned int version) {
    ar & reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(comp)[0];
    ar & reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(comp)[1];
  }
}
```

This by default enables version and class info tracking, which slows code down quite a bit. The serialization function which comes with Boost is a fair bit faster.

I would now like to transition to using the Boost version always when writing out new data files, but still be able to read in old data files. Reading in new files with an old binary is not an issue.

The problem is that the new serialisation is not versioned (obviously). Further, I don’t even see how I could attempt to read in an archive using the old version of the code and immediately write it out again using the new version, as the deserialisation/serialisation traits are global properties.

What would be the best way to either a) transparently read in old and new files while always writing new files or b) reading in an old file and immediately writing it out in the new format?

Comment: "Reading in new files with an old binary is not an issue" - what does that mean

Comment: @sehe: I want to read in old data files with new binaries compiled from new code. I do not want to read in new data files with existing binaries from previous versions of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep the old implementation and use it if the file version is "old".

Use the boost version of complex serialization only when saving or when the file version is "new".

This should be trivial if you have an object containing the complex data to serialize, because can bump the version on the containing object to achieve this

**UPDATE**

Sample, using a simple wrapper to invoke the old style of serialization:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d856b5d4e0e8d30)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/complex.hpp>

template <typename T> struct old_format_wrapper {
    T& wrapped;
    old_format_wrapper(T& w) : wrapped(w) {}
};

template <typename T>
old_format_wrapper<T> old_format(T& w) { return {w}; }

namespace boost { namespace serialization {
    template<class Archive, typename T>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, old_format_wrapper<std::complex<T> >& comp, unsigned) {
            ar & reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(comp.wrapped)[0];
            ar & reinterpret_cast<T(&)[2]>(comp.wrapped)[1];
        }
} }

struct IHaveComplexData {
    std::complex<double> data;

    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned version) {
        switch(version) {
            case 0: { // old
                    auto wrap = old_format(data);
                    ar & wrap;
                }
                break;
            case 1: // new
            default:
                ar & data; // uses boost serialization
                break;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);
        IHaveComplexData o { { 2, 33 } };
        oa << o;
    }

    {
        std::istringstream iss("22 serialization::archive 13 0 0 0 0 2.00000000000000000e+00 3.30000000000000000e+01");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(iss);
        IHaveComplexData o;
        ia >> o;
        std::cout << o.data;
    }
}
```

Prints (depending on your boost version):

```
22 serialization::archive 13 0 0 0 0 2.00000000000000000e+00 3.30000000000000000e+01
(2,33)
```

Of course, you can now set `BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(IHaveComplexData, 1)`

Comment: I am not sure this will work as there are many objects containing this type and the Boost wrappers around `serialize` will expect a version number. That is, how do I tell Boost to sometimes expect a versioned type and sometimes not (of the same class!)?

Comment: Serialization format is a property of your types anyways. Can you show me a sample of what would be tricky/tedious/impossible?

Comment: The Boost serialisation library handles most of the messy bit, i.e. class versioning, class names etc. It then simply calls the `serialize()` function for the class I wish to serialize. The issue is that this class versioning/other overhead, i.e. additional information the Boost library expects, is governed by a type trait of the serialised class. My question is essentially how I can turn that on/off in only parts of the program (the loading bits).

Comment: Wat. Just set the latest version or serialization eg. [`BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(bus_route, 1)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#versioning).

Comment: But I want to switch from a versioned serialisation of `std::complex`  (implementation level `object_class_info`) to a non-versioned serialisation (implementation level `object_serializable`), see e.g. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html#level

Comment: Come on. You told me that several times. I aksed you why you can't just switch the method based on the version of the enclosing object. Perhaps you can _show_, not ---tell--- repeat

Comment: The implementation level is a type trait of the serialised class. This type trait cannot be just switched around to support an object_class_info implementation level during load and a object_serializable implementation level in save, as it is a compile-time constant. If somehow this would be possible and you know how to do that, please do enlighten me, but I have to admit I feel this is not particularly productive.

Comment: Sure. I'm not sure why **I** have to do it, just because you don't see it. Let me add a sample.

Comment: Hm, thanks! I hadn’t thought of using a class wrapper to select the desired implementation! It still requires a wrapper class (`IHaveComplexData`) to be properly versioned, but it seems not entirely impossible to add this everywhere it’s needed. Thanks again! :)